# Pac-Man (collision)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, collision

[My game board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X66pY.png)

Hello , recently I started to deal with the object of Canvas and make the game a series of Atari . I have a question on how to use the methods or Canvas object is best done to my character stopped from touching the walls and move around certain tracks ? I tried to conditions such as:

```
  if (pozX > 180 && pozX < 190) { 
     pozX = 185 
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead doing collision testing...

**Map out the acceptable paths for your game characters**

For example, here is part of your game board.

[image]

Here is a corresponding map of the acceptable paths. "1" represents an allowed move while "0" represents a disallowed move (a game wall). *Edit*: Ouch! I messed up the map in the lower right -- pardons!

[image]

Now you can refer to your acceptable move map when the player presses the arrow keys to move.

For example, if the player starts in the upper left (they start at the "blue 1"). They can move right and down because those moves map to "1"s. But they cannot move up or left because those moves map to "0"s.

Comment: While interesting, your way of doing won't allow for smooth moves. But maybe the O.P. wants to make a turn-based Pacman !! ;-)

Comment: @GameAlchemist. Fair enough ... but I get the idea that the questioner is just beginning their learning of html5 canvas so I present a basic way to get them started. ;-) But yes ... if you want smooth movement you can certainly use linear interpolation to animate them from their starting to their destination map point. And you can use trasformations to rotate your pacman's mouth in the appropriate direction. One step at a time...!

Comment: Thank you for the hints that orient me :) I did a two-dimensional array: tab[ x ] [ y ] and the condition as to the value.

Comment: @Monitxx. Glad to help :-) Good luck with your project!

Comment: @markE : In fact Pacman is not that easy a game to clone, especially if you want a 'natural' way of taking the turns. By the way i quite like the idea of a turn-based Pacman, not to talk about a Pacman RPG !!! :-)

Comment: @markE refreshing to see a classical approach these days :)